# Minted package not working

Tags: minted, pygments

I am having some problems with the package minted. I installed the package and also the package Pygments for python. However I keep getting this error:

> Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this
>   package. \begin{document}

Can everyone give any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is pygmentize in your PATH (i.e. can you run pygmentize from command line)?

Comment: Install the python package pygmentize

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to incorrect installation of an external program

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, pygmentize was not correctly added to the PATH.

Comment: @Herbert This seems to be the answer to the problem.

Comment: Sure, but it should be a comment to the comment

Comment: @Herbert It may be helpful to others with the same issue, so it is an answer.